# When refreshing page state changes problem

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have been using Nextjs and trying to check if my user is logged in trough local storage, but with my current setup when setAuth is true and if the page is refreshed, state sets up to default empty value, and i would like that it remains true as it was set before.Please help.

```
export default function App({Component, pageProps}) {
    const [isAuth, setAuth] = useState('')


    useEffect(() => {
        const storage = localStorage.getItem('isAuth')
        setAuth(storage)
    },[])


    useEffect(() => {

        localStorage.setItem("isAuth", isAuth)
    }, [isAuth])


    return (
        <AppContext.Provider
            value={{
                isAuth,
                setAuth
            }}>
            <Layout>
                <Component {...pageProps} />)
            </Layout>
        </AppContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please give a [mre], you can't call hooks outside of a component or another hook.

Comment: You should be giving the local storage value as the default value for `useState`, rather than updating it during an effect _after_ the component mounts. `const [isAuth, setAuth] = useState(localStorage.getItem('isAuth') || '')`

Comment: i have updated my code, but unfortunately it's not possible to call localStorage in useState in Nextjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to first look at the localStorage value before setting your `isAuth` state value. And because you are using NextJS, you can check if the component is being rendered on client side before applying any client side logic with this: `typeof window !== "undefined"`

If the page is undefined, then it is being rendered on server side, therefore you do not want to use the localStorage API and your authStorage variable will be set to false.

So then your initial state would look something like this:

```js
const authStorage = typeof window !== "undefined" && localStorage.getItem('auth')
const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(authStorage ?? null)
```

This will save you from rendering your component twice. `authStorage ?? null` means if the value does not exist, set value `null`.
Afterwards, you can continue in your component without the need for useEffect functions.

Your code snippet is missing what would happens when the user is not authenticated, but you could redirect to a login page or make use of the `setIsAuth()` inside a function to set both the state value and the localStorage value for the next page render.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible in Nextjs, i would have to do ti with if statement because Nextjs is rendering a server side also and it gives an error if you try to access localStorage.

Comment: I have updated my answer to work with NextJS' server side rendering